# How to evaluate this integral without using numerical method?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \frac{x^2\cos(4\pi x^3)}{1+e^x} dx $$
I tried it using Numerical method and got roughly the same with Wolfram. Are there any other methods to evaluate this integral?

Comment: Use kings rule I.e. f(a+b-x) to cancel the denominator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
I = \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \frac{x^2 \cos \left(4 \pi x^3\right)}{1+e^x}dx\\=\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}\frac{e^x \cos \left(4 \pi x^3\right) x^2}{1+e^x}dx \  (\ \because \int_a^b f(x)=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\ )
$$
Using formula, $\quad \int_{-a}^a f(x)=\int_0^a f(x)+f(-x)$
We get, $I=\int_0^{0.5} x^2 \cos 
 \left(4 \pi x^3\right)dx$
Let $x^3=t ; \quad 3 x^2=d t$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{3} \int_0^\frac{1}{8} \cos (4 \pi t)=\frac{1}{3} \int_0^{1 / 8} \cos ((4 \pi) t) d t \\
\therefore I & =\left.\frac{1}{3} \frac{\sin (4 \pi t)}{4 \pi}\right|_0 ^{1/ 8} \\
& =\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\sin (\frac{\pi}{2})}{4 \pi}-0\right) \\
& \fbox{ I = $\frac{1}{12\pi}$}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks! When I did it your way I got $\frac{1}{12\pi}$. In your solution, should the 3/4 be 1/8?

Comment: @KanNamprohm I put 0.5 in 3x² instead of x³ 

Comment: I've never seen this method before, very nice!